# Swift, Firebase: `setValue` giving error "AnyObject cannot be used with Dictionary Literal"

Tags: swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I am experiencing an error `Contextual type AnyObject cannot be used within dictionary literal` in that func `addPet` down there, while trying to populate database with the `newPet` argument constituents in a dictionary.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

struct Pet {
    var name:String?
    var type:String?
    var age:Int?
    var feedingList:[String]
    var walkingList:[String]
}

struct User {
    var currentId:String?
    var numberOfPets:Int?
    var pets:[Pet]

}

class petBrain {

    var reff = FIRDatabaseReference()
    var currentUser:User = User(currentId: "",numberOfPets: 0,pets: [])

    init(){
        self.reff = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    }

    func setUserId(cId:String?){
        self.currentUser.currentId = cId
    }

    func addPet(newPet:Pet) {
        self.reff.child("pets").childByAutoId().setValue(["name":newPet.name, "type":newPet.type, "age":newPet.age, "fList":newPet.feedingList, "wList":newPet.walkingList])
    }


}
```

I have already done this in other viewController, similarly for users and its working fine in dictionary shape (producing no error)

```
    let em = emailTextField.text!
    let us = usernameTextField.text!

    ...

else {
    print("User created! Loging in.")
    self.login()
    // adding user to DB of users 
    self.ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).setValue(["email":em, "username":us])
}
```

What did i do wrong in the pets case? its maybe due to struct, or struct element types? Are those two structs well defined?

Comment: Are you coding in  swift3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ***?*** is used if the value can become `nil` in the future.
- ***!*** is used if it really shouldn't become nil in the future, but it needs to be nil initially.

See the problem is Swift is a strictly typed language, if you declare a variable *?* you are saying that it's of type nil. So a dictionary cant tell what type of a value would it be storing....

**var myVar : String? // Look `myVar`, you and your type is completely `nil` as of now**

**var myVar : String! // Look `myVar`, your value is `nil` as of now but your type is certainly of `String`**

Just change your code to this:-

```
     struct Pet {
         var name:String!
         var type:String!
         var age:Int!
         var feedingList:[String]
         var walkingList:[String]
     }

     struct User {
         var currentId:String?
         var numberOfPets:Int?
         var pets:[Pet]

     }

     class petBrain {

         var reff = FIRDatabaseReference()
         var currentUser:User = User(currentId: "",numberOfPets: 0,pets: [])

         init(){
             self.reff = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
         }

         func setUserId(cId:String?){
             self.currentUser.currentId = cId
         }

         func addPet(newPet:Pet) {

             let dict = ["name":newPet.name, "type":newPet.type, "age":newPet.age, "fList":newPet.feedingList, "wList":newPet.walkingList]

             self.reff.child("pets").childByAutoId().setValue(dict)
         }


     }
```

Comment: Thank you! And nice explanation, i got it!

Comment: I have updated my answer. Accept my proposed edit , as it might help other user's to easily navigate...